# Check if component is included in page

Tags: javascript, aem

I have a few components in an aem project and they are all being loaded even if the component is included in a specific page or not. As a result all of that javascript is being run and I want to avoid that. Is there a way in Javascript to see if a specific component is included in the page?

P.S: I see a few AEM CQ global objects in the `window` so I was thinking maybe one of those objects would contain which components are included. But I haven't seen anything related or maybe I'm looking at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically on the publisher the AEM CQ global objects do not get loaded, at least the ones that deal with editables. You can simply check for existence of a DOM element added by the component.

When components are added to a layout container, AEM will add the component name as a class on it. You can depend on these auto generated classes to.

```
if($('.myComponent').length < 1){
    return;
}
```

If your goal is to not have the JS itself load, you can include the clientlib at the component level. With HTTP2 number of files to load should not matter, but the OOTB clientlib include tag will still add render blocking scripts. There are workarounds for this where in you collect all clientlibs to be loaded in a request attribute and then include them before the body closing tag. Checkout https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async for how you can use the HTMLLibraryManager to build custom clientlib mechanisms of your own.